# Reportlab , How to change page orientation?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am creating pdf file that containing many pages. I want first page to be portrait and rest of the pages will be landscape. I tried,

`story.append(NextPageTemplate('landscape'))` [refererence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913682/reportlab-how-to-switch-between-portrait-and-landscape)

But I got,

`ValueError: can't find template('landscape') handle_nextPageTemplate args=('landscape',)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured out.

```
doc = BaseDocTemplate("mypdf.pdf", pagesize=A4, rightMargin=25, leftMargin=25, topMargin=25, bottomMargin=25)
portrait_frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='portrait_frame ')
landscape_frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.height, doc.width, id='landscape_frame ')

story= []
story.append(<first-page-content>)
story.append(NextPageTemplate('landscape'))
story.append(PageBreak())
story.append(<second-page-content>)

doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='portrait',frames=portrait_frame),
                      PageTemplate(id='landscape',frames=landscape_frame, pagesize=landscape(A4)),
                      ])
doc.build(story)
```

References:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/123612-basedoctemplate-with-2-pagetemplate/

[Reportlab : How to switch between portrait and landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913682/reportlab-how-to-switch-between-portrait-and-landscape)